# Why is 1 * 4 = 196?

Tags: c++, binary

Im trying to make a binary converter, the problem however is that when I build it, it usually decrypts my test number "101" which should be 5 into something along the lines of 300 - 3000.

```
int main()
{

char a;
string bintered;
int bincrypted = 0, bincrypter;
cout<<"Would you like to try the binary to decimal converter? Y/N"<<endl;
cin>>a;

if (a == 'Y' || a == 'y')
{
    cout<<"Ok, enter a binary number and we will decrypt it > ";
    cin>>bintered;

    int x = bintered.length() - 1; //multiplier counting down
    int y = 0;
    int power = 0;
    while (x != -1)
    {
       power = bintered[y] * pow(2.0, x);
       bincrypted = bincrypted + power;
       y++;
       x = x - 1;
    }

    cout<<"Final answer is: "<<bincrypted<<endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

When I tried doing `cout<<bintered[y] * pow(2.0, x);` it gave me 196, 96 and 49 for the three loops it did. 
Am i using the pow function incorrectly or what?

Comment: `pow` works with floating point numbers, which means there will likely be small errors that will cause problems later on. For powers of two, use bit shifting, such as `x << y` which is the same as `x * 2^y`.

Comment: Computers store numbers in binary anyway, so you could just directly read and write the bits.

Comment: See `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`, so you only need to make one comparison:  `a = std::toupper(a); if (a == 'Y')`

Comment: Be aware that `pow` is a floating point function, and you may have accuracy issues when converting between floating point and integer.  Use bit shifting for powers of 2, e.g. replace `pow(2.0,x)` with `(1 << x)`.  Usually bit shifts are faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bintered[y] returns the ascii code of the character, so 48 for 0 and 49 for 1.

Comment: Ah, is there a better way I could do this then?

Comment: @JeffGoblin Subtract `'0'` since the encoding values for the digits are guaranteed to be consecutive.

Comment: Not the ASCII code but the character code from the character encoding that cin, setlocale and your C++ vendor's standard library startup code and your terminal came up with. It's almost certainly not ASCII but is very likely to be compatible over what Unicode calls the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block. Anyway, as @FeiXiang says, subtract '0' to find the "distance" from the '0' digit to the one in question. '0' would be emitted in the character encoding that you have your compiler using as the "execution charset". Hope all of these line up.